# Save recorded audio file in django from javascript ajax

Tags: javascript, python, django, ajax

I am trying to record audio file using javascript and save in django backend.
Here is ajax function

```
function uploadAudio( blob ) {
  var reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onload = function(event){
    var fd = {};
    fd["data"] = event.target.result;
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'testing/',
      data: fd,
      dataType: 'text'
    }).done(function(data) {
        console.log(data);
        document.getElementById("response").innerHTML=data;
        alert(data);
    });
  };
```

Here is the function in views.py file

```
@csrf_exempt
def test(request):
    if request.is_ajax():
        print("Yes, AJAX!")
        print(request.DATA )
    else:
        print("Not Ajax")

    return render(request,'testing.html',{'print':'message'})
```

How can i save the data as audio file

Answer (score 0):

This is the sloution that worked for me

```
@csrf_exempt
    def test(request):
        if request.is_ajax():
            req=request.POST.get('data')
            d=req.split(",")[1]
            f = open('./file.wav', 'wb')
            f.write(base64.b64decode(d))
            f.close()
        return HttpResponse('audio received')
```

EDIT:
It is not recommended to excempt csrf token, instead send it via ajax this way

```
fd["data"] = event.target.result;
fd["csrfmiddlewaretoken"]=$('input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').val()
```